# jsPDF downloading blank pdf

Tags: jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to generate a pdf from the current HTML, the code works fine if I paste it on the console and downloads a PDF with the current HTML, but when I put it on a JS file it downloads a blank PDF:

This is the code:

```
<script>
  function descargar_pdf(){
      var pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {});
      pdf.save('Estadodecuenta.pdf');
  };
</script>
```

The function is called from a button:

```
<button class="descargar_pdf" id="ignorePDF" onclick="descargar_pdf();"> Descarga tu estado de cuenta</button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second argument in the addHTML function is a callback function which gets called after the HTML is rendered.

```
pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
    pdf.save('*.pdf');
});
```

Comment: For some reason anything inside the `function()` ins't executing.  The canvas is being rendered but the `pdf.save()` isn't being called.

Comment: @DevEng I am facing a similar issue. Have you fixed it?

Comment: @KaviVaidya Sorry, I abandoned this method a while ago.  We just open a new window, add the `HTML` there and force the print window to open.  The user then saves as PDF.

Comment: @DevEng but that will get rid of the CSS, right? Like the top and left attributes are not retained by print thing. Or do you open the new page with just the canvas?

Comment: When we open the new page we pass in the css inside the HTML so they style is reserved.

Answer (score 2):

This may sound stupid but there's a lot of security plugins that see JSPDF as an "unsafe" js and just block it , i had the same problem as you did but after testing it out on incognito mode (no extensions) it worked fine.

This may not the solution to your problem but its a advice you should keep in mind

Answer (score 2):

The last correctly working version of html2canvas is RC1. Downgrade to that one and it should work as expected.